# Apollo federation file upload

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I have a problem in uploading file in apollo federation subgraph, this is my code in apollo gateway

```
import {
ApolloGateway,
// RemoteGraphQLDataSource //replace by FileUploadDataSource from @profusion/apollo-federation-upload for file upload
} from '@apollo/gateway'
import FileUploadDataSource from '@profusion/apollo-federation-upload'
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({ //RemoteGraphQLDataSource 
   serviceList, //port:4010
   buildService: ({ url }) => new FileUploadDataSource({ 
   url, useChunkedTransfer: true }),
   useChunkedTransfer: true,
})
```

In using RemoteGraphQLDataSource from @apollo/gateway this the result of file upload
[image]

the error is BadRequestError: Missing multipart field ‘operations’.

but when I am directing the request from the service list, the file is uploaded
[image]
upon searching for it I find this solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/@profusion/apollo-federation-upload then replace **RemoteGraphQLDataSource** to **FileUploadDataSource** but the output is the same

can anybody help me about this? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by setting `uploads:false` since I am using apollo 2 in this set up

https://github.com/profusion/apollo-federation-file-upload/issues/35

Comment: Im using apollo server 3, still getting the "operations" missing error on the service. If you have tried with apollo 3, can you help me here.